# supports-screens is not working for the right screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

i have included this code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

I have also created layout for normal, large, and xlarge layout. when i run the app on large screens. it ignores the large layout and runs the normal instead. Does anyone knows what am i doing wrong?

For xlarge screens it runs the xlarge as expected

Comment: Whatever your problem is, it has nothing to do with `<supports-screens>`, as that does not control which resources get used.

Comment: so what's control it? normal and xlarge are working but not large

Comment: My guess is that the device that you think uses `large` resources does not. What device are you using to test? How have you determined that it should use `large` resources?

Comment: i tried on samsung j7 and nexus 6 both should use large resources

Comment: when i select a device in virtual device configuration next to nexus 6 for example the size is large , ration : long , density:xxhdpi

Comment: Well, an actual Nexus 6 device uses `normal` resources, and `Configuration` on that device reports that it has `SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL`.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that few developers use those screen size buckets. It is *much* more flexible to use ones where you specify the dividing line, such as `layout-w600dp` (which means "use these resources when the current width is 600dp or larger").

Comment: thanks i will research more about layout-w600dp.

Comment: so how many different dividing lines i should make?

Comment: Ask your graphic designer. Or, whatever you feel like. Some apps use none. Some use one. Some use a few.